# Is there a way in Python to Multiply names with value? CSV

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

i have a csv file which has names and a number. I want that name gets multiplied by the value and stored in a dictionary. If there is no value than the name should be skipped.

```
Nicole  15,
Heike   20,
Markus  32,
Carmen  23,
Holger   ,
Carolin  ,
Marcin  16,
Vero    12,
Sabine  16,
Peter   32,
Nicole   ,
Markus S    15,
```

for example to look like this

```
´´´people = {"sachbearbeiter" : ["Nicole", "Nicole", "Nicole", "Nicole", "Nicole", "Nicole", "Nicole", "Nicole", "Nicole", "Nicole", "Nicole", "Nicole", "Nicole", "Nicole", "Nicole", "Heike", "Heike", "Heike", "Heike", "Heike", "Heike", and so on]}´´´
```

So that i can load this series and append it to my dataframe. Because i have a list of cases which i need to give to my employees.

Thanks

Comment: `print(['hello'] * 3) ` should print `['hello', 'hello', 'hello']`

Answer (score 0):

why not using a loop ?

```
l=[("Nicole",3),("Bob",2)]

r=[]

for i in l:
   for j in range(0,i[1]):
      r.append(i[0])

print(r)
```

or indeed multiplication

```
l=[("Nicole",3),("Bob",2),("Chloe",0)]

r=[]

for i in l:
    if (i[1]!=0):
        r=r+i[1]*[i[0]]



print(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your examples. If you have a number but no value, or no value and no number, you'll have to write some code to handle that. (Assuming the csv is called `sachbearbeiter.csv`).

```
import csv

def csv2list(source_name):
    with open(source_name, encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        read_csv = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        return list(read_csv)

people = {"sachbearbeiter": []}

for line in csv2list("sachbearbeiter.csv"):
    t = line[0].rsplit(None, 1)
    if t[-1].isdigit():
        people["sachbearbeiter"].extend(int(t[1])*[t[0]])
```